# SQLite, ORDER BY name if group doesnt exist

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order a list by alphabetical name, unless that row has a group, then I want the group to be used. `grouped` can also be NULL or an empty string.

For example:

```
name      grouped
a         NULL
b         
c         a 
d
```

Would be ordered as:

```
a,c,b,d
```

Here's what I have

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(grouped, name)
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY CASE WHEN LENGTH(grouped) = 0 
THEN name ELSE grouped END
```

But neither of these solutions work properly, they end up having all the grouped items show up first, not inter-mingled with the names as I would expect.

Comment: What do you get with your `COALESCE` order?  It should work.  Is `grouped` possibly empty string instead of actually null?

Comment: @Holt: CONCAT is, AFAIK, a MySQLism, the official operator for string concatenation is `||`. Also, `null || anything` is `null` so that won't help as is.

Comment: @SamuelNeff, hm, i guess there are some instances where it is an empty string. So it can be null or empty

Comment: Please update your question with a description of the ways in which “neither of these solutions work properly”. Also, what is the value of `grouped` in the case of `b` and `d` above? There _must_ be a value, even if it is `NULL`…

Comment: @DonalFellows, there is an empty string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CASE COALESCE(grouped, '')
         WHEN '' THEN name
                 ELSE grouped
         END,
         COALESCE(grouped, '') <> ''
```

Comment: That still orders all grouped items ahead of non grouped items.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, there was an issue with case. grouped was all capitalized, and name was not. Capital letters get sorted first.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a mix of null and empty string, do this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
ORDER BY COALESCE(grouped, '') || name;
```

This will change nulls to empty string, leave empty string as empty string, and concatenate name.

Comment: Hm, that seems to order all the groups AHEAD of all the names.